# What do I need to bribe the Gravedigger in Vizima?

Tags: the-witcher

I can't find anyway to access the cemetery in Vizima... the Gravedigger won't let me bribe him whatever I try to give him (booze, jewelry, food, drugs...). And then he is upset, and I can't talk to him for a moment.

I there anything that he will accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember clearly but it was something like talking to Thaler about the gravedigger's debts. Thaler vanishes gravedigger's debts and after that graveyard is accessible.

Comment: There's also option of getting pass from the "suspected" cop, if you get his trust.